# python requests keep connection alive for indefinite time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to get a python script running which calls an external API (to which I only have read-access) in a certain interval, the API uses cookie-based authentication: Calling the `/auth` endpoint initially sets session cookies which are then used for authentication in further requests.

As for my problem: Because the authentication is based on an active session, the cookies aren't valid once the connection drops, and therefore has to be restarted. From what I've read, `requests` is based on `urllib3`, which keeps the connection alive by default. Yet, after a few tests I noticed that under some circumstances, the connection will be dropped anyway.

I used a `Session` object from the `requests` module and I've tested how long it takes for the connection to be dropped as follows:

```
from requests import session
import logging
import time import time, sleep

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def tt(interval):
    credentials = {"username":"user","password":"pass"}
    s = Session()
    r = s.post("https://<host>:<port>/auth", json=credentials)
    ts = time()
    while r.status_code is 200:
        r = s.get("https://<host>:<port>/some/other/endpoint")
        sleep(interval)
    return time() - ts # Seconds until connection drop
```

Might not be the best way to find that out, but I let that function run twice, once with an interval of 1 second and then with an interval of 1 minute. Both had run for about an hour until I had to manually stop the execution.

However, when I swapped the two lines within the `while` loop, which meant that there was a 1-minute-delay after the initial `POST /auth` request, the following `GET` request failed with a `401 Unauthorized` and this message being logged beforehand:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: <host>
```

As the interval of requests may range from a few minutes to multiple hours in my prod script, I have to know beforehand how long these sessions are kept alive and whether there are some exceptions to that rule (like dropping the connection if no request after the initial `POST /auth` is made for a short while).

So, how long does `requests` or rather `urllib3` keep the connection alive, and is it possible to extend that time indefinitely?

Or is it the server instead of `requests` that drops the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `requests.Session`, [keep-alive is handled for you automatically](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive).

In the first version of your loop that continuously polls the server after the `/auth` call is made, the server does not drop the connection due to the subsequent `GET` that happens.  In the second version, it's likely that sleep interval exceeds the amount of time the server is configured to keep the connection open.

Depending on the server configuration of the API, the response headers may include a `Keep-Alive` header with information about how long connections are kept open at a minimum.  `HTTP/1.0` specifies this information is included in the `timeout` parameter of the `Keep-Alive` header.  You could use this information to determine how long you have until the server will drop the connection.

In `HTTP/1.1`, persistent connections are used by default and the `Keep-Alive` header is not used unless the server explicitly implements it for backwards compatibility.  Due to this difference, there isn't an immediate way for a client to determine the exact timeout for connections since it may exist solely as server side configuration.

The key to keeping the connection open would be to continue polling at regular intervals.  The interval you use must be less than the server's configured connection timeout.

One other thing to point out is that artificially extending the length of the session indefinitely this way makes one more vulnerable to [session fixation attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).  You may want to consider adding logic that occasionally reestablishes the session to minimize risk of these types of attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding the vulnerability! Btw, is there a possibility aside of trial and error to get the exact time interval until timeout if the `Keep-Alive` header isn't set in the response?

Comment: @AhmedBajra I think from the client's perspective, that may be your only option without the response header.  I updated my answer to reflect this.